# asp.net mvc model database change

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've used mvcScaffolding and mvc3 to generate my tables in a sql2008 database.  some data has been added.

I've changed a single model and wish to alter the underlying table.

1. is there a way to auto-update a single table to keep it in sync with the model?
2. after adding a new model how can the database table be created without recreating the database

Comment: What exactly are you using to generate the initial schema for the database? EF Code-First? NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like Rails' migrations. There are a [couple .NET migrations providers](http://nuget.org/Packages/Packages/Details/FluentMigrator-0-9-0-0) floating around, but the basic setup you've described doesn't support alterations to the schema without recreating the database (at least in my experience).

Comment: I should note my answer is assuming you're using EF (Code First) since you mentioned mvcscaffolding.

Comment: you are correct, what I'm looking for is not in the scaffolding yet.  I need to somehow turn it off; then i can supply my own database updater.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried treating your database an an existing one as described in this example by Scott Gu?

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx

Hopefully thias way you will not have to re-create your db everytime a change is required...

Regards

Paul